# i cannot delete row from SQLiteDatabase

Tags: sqlite, android-listview, contextmenu

In my code when i search then a listview creates from database.i want to delete row of table from here.i used context menu.there is a Book.java file for getter and setter. everything goes fine but when i press delete then ok the program stops.I think the problem is in processDelete function.I also cannot get the id from my table because rowId is id from the list. Please help me quickly.i can't do anything without this.

`

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EmployeeList extends ListActivity {

    protected EditText searchText;
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;
    protected Cursor cursor;
    protected ListAdapter adapter;
    public Integer pid=null;
    public DatabaseHelper databaseHelper=new DatabaseHelper(null);       //my database(I gave parameter null because i don't know what to give)
    public Book book;                                                    //getter setter
    private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST+3;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
        searchText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.searchText);

    }

    public void search(View view) {
        // || is the concatenation operation in SQLite
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "insert successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, firstName, lastName, title FROM employee WHERE firstName || ' ' || lastName LIKE ?", 
                new String[]{"%" + searchText.getText().toString() + "%"});
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this, 
        R.layout.employee_list_item, 
        cursor, 
        new String[] {"firstName", "lastName", "title"}, 
        new int[] {R.id.firstName, R.id.lastName, R.id.title});
setListAdapter(adapter);
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    }
    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EmployeeDetails.class);
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
        intent.putExtra("EMPLOYEE_ID", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"))); **strong text**
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

menu.add(Menu.NONE, DELETE_ID, Menu.NONE, "Delete")
.setAlphabeticShortcut('d');
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case DELETE_ID:
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info=
(AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();

delete(info.id);
return(true);
}

return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
private void delete(final long rowId) {
    if (rowId>0) {
      new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle(R.string.delete_title)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {

            processDelete(rowId);
          }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
          // ignore, just dismiss
          }
        })
        .show();
    }
  }
private void processDelete(long rowId) {                           //I get exact rowid.
    String[] args={String.valueOf(rowId)};    

    databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase().delete("employee", "_ID=?", args); //employee is table name and _ID is id column(here i get nullPointerException)
    cursor.requery();
  }
}`
```

Database helper class:

`
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

```
  public static final String DB_NAME = "employee_directory"; 
    public static final Integer VERSION=1;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME= "employee";
    public static final String _id= "id";
    public static final String firstName= "firstName";
    public static final String lastName= "lastName";
    public static final String title= "title";
    public static final String officePhone= "officePhone";
    public static final String cellPhone= "cellPhone";
    public static final String email= "email";

    public static final String TABLE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME+" (" +_id+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
    + firstName+ " TEXT, " + lastName+ " TEXT, " + title+ " TEXT, " + officePhone+ " TEXT, " + cellPhone+" TEXT, " + email+" TEXT)";
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("TABLE SQL", TABLE_SQL);
        db.execSQL(TABLE_SQL);

            }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employees");
    onCreate(db);
}
//  public void delete(int pos) {
   //     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    //    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, _id + " = ?",
     //           new String[] { String.valueOf(pos)});
      //  db.close();
 //   }

    //public void delete(String value1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //  getWritableDatabase().delete(TABLE_NAME, "id=?", new String[] { value1 });  

    //}
```

}`

Logcat says i am getting NullPointerException.Is there something wrong in my delete query?

logcat:

`

```
07-28 20:10:23.384: E/AndroidRuntime(977): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-28 20:10:23.384: E/AndroidRuntime(977): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-28 20:10:23.384: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
07-28 20:10:23.384: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at com.example.intent.EmployeeList.processDelete(EmployeeList.java:124)
07-28 20:10:23.384: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at com.example.intent.EmployeeList.access$0(EmployeeList.java:115)
07-28 20:10:23.384: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at com.example.intent.EmployeeList$1.onClick(EmployeeList.java:101)
07-28 20:10:23.384: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:158)
07-28 20:10:23.384: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-28 20:10:23.384: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-28 20:10:23.384: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-28 20:10:23.384: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 20:10:23.384: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-28 20:10:23.384: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-28 20:10:23.384: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-28 20:10:23.384: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

`
```

Those are solved by inserting this.but still there are some errors.

```
08-09 02:09:52.955: E/Database(310): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.example.intent/databases/employee_directory' 
08-09 02:09:52.955: E/Database(310): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
08-09 02:09:52.955: E/Database(310):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1810)
08-09 02:09:52.955: E/Database(310):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:817)
08-09 02:09:52.955: E/Database(310):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:851)
08-09 02:09:52.955: E/Database(310):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:844)
08-09 02:09:52.955: E/Database(310):    at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:540)
08-09 02:09:52.955: E/Database(310):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
08-09 02:09:52.955: E/Database(310):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
08-09 02:09:52.955: E/Database(310):    at com.example.intent.EmployeeList.onCreate(EmployeeList.java:44)
08-09 02:09:52.955: E/Database(310):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-09 02:09:52.955: E/Database(310):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-09 02:09:52.955: E/Database(310):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-09 02:09:52.955: E/Database(310):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-09 02:09:52.955: E/Database(310):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-09 02:09:52.955: E/Database(310):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-09 02:09:52.955: E/Database(310):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-09 02:09:52.955: E/Database(310):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-09 02:09:52.955: E/Database(310):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-09 02:09:52.955: E/Database(310):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-09 02:09:52.955: E/Database(310):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-09 02:09:52.955: E/Database(310):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-09 02:09:52.955: E/Database(310):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

how will i solve the cursor problem?

Comment: Probably there are error message, add traceback from logcat to your answer

Comment: It shows NullPointerException on databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase().delete("employee", "_ID=?", args); this line.what will i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the database helper, you call

```
public DatabaseHelper databaseHelper=new DatabaseHelper(null);
```

But `null` is wrong. If you look into docs about `Context` you see that e.g. `Activity` is a known indirect subclass. Your current activity is the context here:

```
public DatabaseHelper databaseHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

**EDIT:**

As constructor definition

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
```

tells, a parameter of type `Context` is required for creating a `DatabaseHelper`. A `Context` object delivers information about a particular application and provides services related to an application.

Instead of a `Context` an object of a subclass can be used like e.g. `ListActivity`. In the docs you can see that `ListActivity` extends `Activity` which in turn extends `ContextThemeWrapper` and so on up to `Context`. Each object of one of these classes can be used where a `Context` object is required as parameter (at least formally, depending on the use case there may be objects which don't work in practice).

Your `EmployeeList` extends `ListActivity` and therefore can also be used as context. The keyword `this` in a method always refers to the object on which method was called, e.g. in a call

```
obj.foo()
```

`this` in `foo()` would then mean the same object which is referred to by `obj`.

In the particular case at the beginning, `this` refers to an `EmployeeList` object.

Comment: Yap that was the problem.Thanks for your help.As it is solved its time to fall in another problem.Hope you'll help again.

Comment: can u tell me what DatabaseHelper(this) means,Because context is in another class.so why "this".As i am a slow learner explain it easily.

Comment: That was helpful.I got another problem.I created another table in same database,not working.it cannot find the new table.Unsigned Long thanks again.